# What is the difference between setting font-size in the body and in the html elements of a web page?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

In my application I set the text size like this:

```
html {
font-size: 58%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
/* font-size: 1.5rem; */
}

body {
font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

This results in this size of font when I inspect some text:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
```

However I tried this:

```
html {
font-size: 58%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Now the result is much larger text.

Can someone help explain to me should I use the HTML element or the BODY element to set my base font size. Note that all of the application sets everything in rem units. I just want to do this the correct way so it will adapt well also to different media sizes later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in your first example is the following:

1. You set your font-size to 58 %, if the default size would be 16px then 58 % of that is 9.28px.
2. Next you set your font-size to 1.5rem in your `body` selector, which basically means that u scale 9.28px with 150 % (9.28 * 1.5 = 13.92) And there you have your 14px.

In your second example your second `font-size` (1.5rem) will override your first declaration of `font-size` (58%) making your font-size 1.5rem out of default (normally 16px), this should make you end up with 24px.

What I usually do is to set my `font-size` to `62.5%` (58% in your case) in my `html` tag selector, and then in my `body` I just set it to 100% (which means 100% out of 62.5%).

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you tell me where would I normally set the size. Should I do it in the HTML or the body?

Comment: @SamanthaJ You are welcome, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Piers. I upvoted both you and Jarek but I accepted your answer because it came one minute earlier.

Answer (score 3):

When you set it for the `body`, 1.5rem means 1.5 times the font size of the `html`, which is 1.5 * 58% = 87%.

In the second case, the way CSS works is the last-declared value for a property is used and the previous are discarded (rather than multiplied as the case with different elements). In other words `html { font-size: 58%; font-size: 1.5rem; }` is the same as `html { font-size: 1.5rem; }` which is the same as `font-size: 150%`.

Font-sizing with `rem` units will modify font-size declared on the `html` element, so you should set your desired base font size in `html`. Declaring it on `body` will work in simple cases, but using `rem` to change font-size on lower elements (`div`s, etc) will base off the `html` value anyway, which would get confusing.

Comment: Thanks Jarek, What would you recommend me to do. Should I set in the body or the HTML? Also is it recommended for a simple standard web page to change from the default by using font-size more or less than one?

Comment: I edited my answer slightly to address body-vs-html.

Comment: Thanks Jarek. I would have liked to accept both answers but can only accept one so I accepted the one from Piers as it was slightly earlier. Hope you understand. Oh I upvoted your answer also. Thanks